# visible binding of array elements in knockout based on their property

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observable array which holds multiple objects, each object has a boolean property called `display`.

```
var markers = [];
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    // Observable arrya
    self.dineList = ko.observableArray([]);
}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// data is data from ajax request
function createMarker(data) {
    markers = [];

    data.forEach(function(data) {
        var marker = {
            title: 'abc',
            display: true,
            // and other properties
        }
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    viewModel.dinelist(markers);
}
```

I display all the markers in a list on a page.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: dineList">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.title"></li>
</ul>
```

Initially all the elements have `display: true`and it works fine, but I want to toggle the value of `display` based on certain conditions and also the visibility of `li` items based on their `display` property. I am able to toggle the value of `display` of all elements in `markers` array but not in `dineList` array.

Comment: try making them observables `display: ko.observable(true)`. They are updated initially to `true`, hence they are working only then

Comment: @gkb I tried it but it doesn't seem to work, `<li data-bind="visible: $data.display(), text: $data.title"></li>` . I also checked the value of `display` property after every change and it is changing but the `li`s are always visible.

Comment: @gkb It worked, turns out after toggling the `display` value in my function, I was changing it back to `true`, every time. Thanks for the help.